# MSAL Scopes (openid profile offline_access). Basic Simple Profiles May Not be Possible?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

MSAL behaves as though there is a hard-coded catch 22 at its API library layer that seems illogical when I use it.

```
string[] scopesArrayNonNullWORKS = new string[] { "email" };
string[] scopesArrayAlreadyThereInMsalCalls_FAILS = new string[] { "openid" };
string[] scopesArrayNoExtraScopesNeeded_FAILS = new string[0]; 

Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplication myCliApp; 
myCliApp.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, scopesArray);
```

MSAL has built in and hard coded these scopes on every call: ***openid , profile , offline_access*** .

This is fine and works for me.   I have no need for any additional scopes.

However, I can’t use null or an empty scopes list.  It is like the MSAL library layer is forcing me to ask for scopes I do not need or want.  If I include email (which I don’t’ need) then the library layer is happy with a non-null Scopes parameter and everything works.

If I use the one scope I need, *openid*, then the library layer errors because I have included a duplicate scope *openid* which was already there.

This seems like a catch 22 and cyclically illogical.  I can’t use the scopes I need, or, it errors because they are predefined.  I can’t pass in an empty list of scopes (and use the pre-defined) or it errors.  If I pass in a non-null scope that I do not want or need then it works.

I must be missing a critical conceptual detail.

I would like to use these 3 and only these 3 scopes ...  *openid , profile , offline_access* .

*An Error Example of this catch 22: MSAL always sends the scopes 'openid profile offline_access'. They cannot be suppressed as they are required for the library to function. Do not include any of these scopes in the scope parameter.*

Answer (score 1):

The question wasn't really formulated as a question, but if your question is really "is it possible to authenticate to a application which doesn't require additional scopes", then I found a workaround which is definitely a hack and may not work forever.  I couldn't throw in any placeholder scopes to make the client API happy, because the server rejected them.  But sending in a blank space made the API shut up and did not seem to affect the application at all.

`string[] scopes = new[] {" "};`